# Change the value of a date field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to take a field(DateRequired for example) and adjust the date being displayed to show differently from the actual date? For example, if the date in DateRequired is 7/20/17, I would like it to display 7/13/17, a week before the actual date.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, SSRS utilizes VB as a language for custom expressions and code that you create in the report.  If you right-click on the object that your date is in (textbox/table cell etc...) and go to the "Expression" wizard, you will be able to modify your date field.

To add or remove a specific amount of time to a date, utilize the [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, CDate(Fields!YourDateColumn.Value))
```